How to generate pdf using Pyppeteer in django rest?
Need to generate a pdf file from endpoint to which the user must be logged in.
Here is the problem how to with Pyppeteer log into django and access the view.
I have an application in django rest framework where I need to generate a pdf, I use Pyppeteer==0.2.6 for this.
In the view where "permission_class" is set to "AllowAny" everything is OK.
I have an endpoint where I need to be logged in and this is where the problem arises. I get a message in the console that the object is not there, while in fact it is.
My code:
    async def render_page_as_pdf(self, url, sentinel=SENTINEL):
        page = await self.browser_page()
        await page.emulateMedia('print')

        await page.goto('http://localhost:8000/api/auth/login/?next=/api/rest-auth/user/')
        await page.type('#id_username', 'username@test.com')
        await page.type('#id_password', 'my_pass')
        await page.click('#submit-id-submit')

        try:
            await page.evaluate(f"""() => window.goto("{url}")""")
        except PyppeteerError:
            await page.goto(url)
        try:
            await page.waitFor(sentinel, timeout=self.timeout, visible=True)
            return await page.pdf(
                format=self.page_format,
                timeout=self.timeout,
                printBackground=True,
            )
        except (TimeoutError, PyppeteerError):
            logger.exception(f'error to generate pdf: {url}')
        return None

Console output:
"GET /document/sale/31/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Forbidden: /api/rest-auth/user/
Forbidden: /api/rest-auth/user/
172.19.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2024 13:41:48] "GET /api/rest-auth/user/ HTTP/1.1" 403 -
Not Found: /api/documentsales/31/
Not Found: /api/documentsales/31/
172.19.0.1 - - [01/Jul/2024 13:41:48] "GET /api/documentsales/31/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -

My goal is to generate a pdf document. I tried to add login to api page, to admin, but without positive result.

do you really need Pyppeteer to access API? Usually it needs only requests or urllib

without access to django it hard to say how it really work and what can make problem. It may need to use print() or logging in django to see what it get and if it is correct.
